# IF else in Switch Case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
int flag = 0;
char a = 'b';
switch(a) {
  case 'a':
    cout << "In a";
    break;
  if(flag!=0) {
    case 'b':
      cout << "In b";
      break;
  }
  case 'c':
    cout << "In c";
    break;
  default:
    cout << "In d";
}
```

Can someone explain why the above code is printing "In b"?
As per my understanding, it should print "In d"

Comment: A `case` label is like a `goto` label.

Comment: I have duplicated your result: [https://ideone.com/zIrqAk](https://ideone.com/zIrqAk)

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device

Comment: `case 'a':
    cout << "In a";
    break;
  if(flag!=0) {
    case 'b':
      cout << "In b";
      break;
  }` Will never reach your `if` because you already broke out of that `case` with the `break` statement just above it.

Comment: You can search for Duff's device, it uses the same principle

Comment: @SteveWilson it's more of Pigeon's device

Comment: [http://pigeonsnest.co.uk/stuff/pigeons-device.html](http://pigeonsnest.co.uk/stuff/pigeons-device.html)

Comment: Here is a recursive solution that does what you want to do: https://godbolt.org/z/41o819 by combining `if` and `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `case 'a':` is effectually a label to which the control flow is redirected at `switch (a)`. In addition to not being able to modify compile-time structures, an if statement couldn't prevent this redirection simply because it is never reached in beforehand, as a result of aforementioned semantic.

Comment: If addition to mentioning "how", you could state the end result: you cannot enable/disable any case label by logic around it.

Comment: Edited with an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

the `switch case` mechanism is like `goto` call its jump to the relevant `case` if you will look at the assembly code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PvWPab) you will see that it translate to CMP and jmp or je  command